# Run console command in scala

Tags: scala

I want to run this command in Scala, although I am facing all sorts of errors:

```
sed -i '.back' 's/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g' /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

or

```
sed -i '.back' "s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g" /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

I have listed all my tries here (none works). What is the right way to run this command?

Try 1:

```
scala> val command = "sed -i '.back' 's/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g' /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf"
scala> command.! 
sed: 1: "'s/maxTablesPerQuestion ...": invalid command code '
res25: Int = 1
```

Try 2: with double quotations:

```
scala> val command = "sed -i '.back' \"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\" /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf"
scala> command.! 
sed: 1: ""s/maxTablesPerQuestion ...": invalid command code "
res26: Int = 1
```

Try 3: With `Seq`:

```
scala> val command = Seq("sed -i '.back' \"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\" /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf")
scala> command.! 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sed -i '.back' "s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g" /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 33 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 36 more
```

Try 4: with `Seq`:

```
scala> val command = Seq("sed -i '.back' \"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\"", "/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf")

scala> command.!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sed -i '.back' "s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g"": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 33 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 36 more
```

Try 5: with `Seq`:

```
scala> val command = Seq("sed -i '.back'", "\"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\"", "/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf")

scala> command.!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sed -i '.back'": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 33 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 36 more
```

Try 6:

```
scala> val command = Seq("sed -i", "'.back'", "\"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\"", "/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf")

scala> command.!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sed -i": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 33 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 36 more
```

Try 7: with `Seq`:

```
scala> val command = Seq("sed", "-i", "'.back'", "\"s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g\"", "/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf")

scala> command.!
sed: 1: ""s/maxTablesPerQuestion ...": invalid command code "
res34: Int = 1
```

Comment: `sed` is presumably not on the PATH. Why not try some simpler command to test this before getting the `sed` and all its parameters right. `which sed` might be a good choice :)

Comment: `"sed".!` works fine!

Comment: have you ever tried `command !` (command being a string, and without the dot)? Also, can you try `val result = "sed -i '.back' 's/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g' /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf" ! ` ?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to execute system commands in Scala is to use the "Sequence syntax" (see code). The long string with escape characters is much more tedious to get right. I almost never had any issues when using this syntax.

One thing to note is that you no longer need to use the single `'` or double quotes `"` to define the segments of your command. The sequence already gives all the details needed to the `sed` (or any other command).

Give it a try, let me know if it doesn't do exactly what you needed.

```
import sys.process._

Seq("sed","-i",".back","s/maxTablesPerQuestion/maxTablesPerQuestion = 2.0 /g", "/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/aristo/solvers/tableilp/src/main/resources/application.conf").!
```

Comment: Can't believe this worked after trying everything else. Thanks!